# Turning off webcam record light on HP Pavilion dv7

Tags: windows-7

Is there a way to turn off my HP Pavilion dv7's webcam record light?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? If the little light bothers you for some reason, you can draw over it with a black permanent marker. It's not particularly bright, though, so I don't see why that would be an issue.

Comment: The main idea behind this is that the user shouldn't get aware that he's being recorded.

Comment: This is an old post.  But if the purpose is to conceal that the person is being recorded, as ott suggests, be aware that there may be legal ramifications.  You can just cover the LED with a piece of tape for most legit purposes.  If you're recording someone else, investigate the need for disclosure.

Answer (score 0):

I only found one way, and that was to disable the webcam device driver.  Obviously not a good solution if you want to use the webcam, but easy enough if you don't want to use it.

Comment: Do you mean that it's on all the time even if you're not using it? If so, then some application is recording (spying on) you all the time!

Answer (score -1):

You need enter to Device Manager, Locate the Device in Properties Select Disable, when the Light turn off then Select Enable!

Comment: Could you please try to reword your answer? I don't understand anything past the first sentence.

Answer (score -1):

this solution I found in some forums looks like functional

find the key, Dword-data in directory and change it.it varies by brand

```
HKEY\LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class\\{6bdd...}
```

it might be hard to find, look for keyword LED ON OFF
it's probably in the properties or settings key you Can see Driver ID, Device ID and else USEFUL INFORMATION to identify the webcam.

after you have done the changes EXIT REGISTERY EDITOR _ Log off turn off _ so you can see the effects ruining the basic OPERATING OF WEBCAM

Comment: This is quite difficult to read and understand just what we are looking to change in the Registry.  Are you able to provide a link to the source so we can see for ourselves?